Handling errors and exceptions for API responses
I am looking for a better way to handle errors and exceptions.
I want to catch the exception and pass it back to the caller of this function. But the method signature is <LoginResponseDto, ErrorResponseDto> The ErrorResponseDto is the model I will get back when the API return a status code error. However, its possible a exception could be thrown and I would like to bubble that up to the caller as well.
I am not sure its possible with my current implementation.
What is the best way to handle something like this
   override suspend fun loginUser(loginRequestModel: LoginRequestModel): APIResponse<LoginResponseDto, ErrorResponseDto> {
            return try {
                val response = httpClient
                    .post("https://endpoint") {
                        contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
    
                        setBody(
                            LoginRequestDto(
                               /* body data */
                            )
                        )
                    }
    
                if (response.status.value == 200) {
                    APIResponse.OnSuccess(response.body())
                }
                else {
                    APIResponse.OnFailure(response.body())
                }
            }
            catch (exception: Exception) {
                if (exception is CancellationException) {
                    Timber.e(exception)
                    throw exception
                }
                else {
                    Timber.e(exception)
                    // This works as I am still return the ErrorResponseDto but looks hacky doing it like this
                    APIResponse.OnFailure(ErrorResponseDto(
                        errors = listOf(
                            ErrorDto(
                                code = exception.localizedMessage ?: "",
                                detail = exception.message ?: "Unknown"))))

                    // But what I would want to do is this
                    // APIResponse.OnFailure(exception) 
                }
            }
        }
    
       interface APIResponse<out T, out E> {
            data class OnSuccess<T>(val data: T) : APIResponse<T, Nothing>
            data class OnFailure<E>(val error: E) : APIResponse<Nothing, E>
        }
    
        data class ErrorResponseDto(
            val errors: List<ErrorDto>
        )
    
        data class ErrorDto(
            val code: String,
            val detail: String
        )


Some preferences of mine, based on separation of concerns, which might give you some ideas for your own solution.
CONSUMING VIEW
The view originates processing by instructing its view model to call an API. On error the consuming view might present child error views.
An error summary view might present a basic message. On clicking it you might get an error details modal dialog that renders your code and detail, and possibly other details.
CONSUMING VIEW MODEL
The view model is where the API error is caught and where the error view model is populated. Yet it is not where you implement the plumbing. Instead, aim to write only business-focused code, like this:
try {
  val result = loginClient.loginUser(request)
  withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
    updateData(result)
  }

} catch (error: AppError) {
   withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
    updateError(error)
  }
}

SERVICE AGENT PATTERN
For each remote API, like your login service, use a dedicated class to interact with it, that implements any plumbing, like translating from API error responses to the app's error view model.
SCALABILITY
My goals for a frontend app are often to build many views and view models with simple code, while plumbing code, like that involved in remote calls, is externalised. I think the above pattern meets those requirements.
SUMMARY
In your case, I would make your loginUser logic a service agent method. Its return type should be LoginResponseDto.
On failure, loginUser would throw an error that is easy for the view model to use. Eg it might translate from ErrorResponseDto to AppError.

What if you have the methods for constructing the Success and the Failure instances with an overloaded method that could accept an exception and return APIResponse<Nothing, ErrorResponseDto>?
interface APIResponse<out T, out E> {
    data class Success<T>(val data: T) : APIResponse<T, Nothing>
    data class Failure<E>(val error: E) : APIResponse<Nothing, E>

    companion object {
        fun <T> onSuccess(data: T) = Success(data)
        fun <E> onFailure(error: E) = Failure(error)

        fun onFailure(cause: Exception): APIResponse<Nothing, ErrorResponseDto> {
            return Failure(ErrorResponseDto(
                errors = listOf(
                    ErrorDto(
                        code = cause.localizedMessage ?: "",
                        detail = cause.message ?: "Unknown"))))
        }
    }
}

That way, you can simplify the code that handles the HTTP response by using the APIResponse.OnFailure(exception).

I personally set up client to expect success then instead of returning weird typed interfaces use kotlin.Result that encapsulates all errors.
Only thing to keep in mind is that Ktor will give us ResponseException when http call itself is the reason of failure.
override suspend fun loginUser(loginRequestModel: LoginRequestModel): Result<LoginResponseDto> = 
    runCatching {
        // note that client is set up to expect success so it will throw when response code is not 200
        httpClient
            .post("https://endpoint") {
                contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
                setBody(LoginRequestDto(/* body data */))
            }.body()
    }.onFailure {
        // bubble up cancellation
        if (it is CancellationException) throw it
    }

Now in the call site all that remains is:
api.loginUser(loginModel).fold (
    onSuccess = { loginDto -> handleSuccessfullLogin(loginDto) },
    onFailure = { error ->
        when (error) {
            is ResponseException -> { // http call failed here
                error.response.status // returned code and message is here
            }
            else -> { /* other causes */ }
        }
    }
)


Note how ResponseException does contain full HttpResonse which means that we can attempt to get error .body() as well if its needed.

In big projects, the most important thing to keep in mind is separation of concerns, and general code readability/maintainability. Your code is mostly fine but you can standardize/improve it by defining an API Error class with the well known exceptions that can occur. Something like:
sealed class APIErrorException(message: String, cause: Throwable? = null) : Exception(message, cause) {
    class InvalidCredentialsException(message: String) : APIErrorException(message)
    class AccessDeniedException(message: String) : APIErrorException(message)
    class ResourceNotFoundException(message: String) : APIErrorException(message)
    class UnknownAPIException(message: String) : APIErrorException(message)
}

You can then update your APIResponse interface and use in your code like below:
sealed interface APIResponse<out T, out E : Exception> {
    data class Success<T>(val data: T) : APIResponse<T, Nothing>
    data class Failure<E>(val error: E) : APIResponse<Nothing, E>
    data class Error(val exception: Exception) : APIResponse<Nothing, Nothing>
}

override suspend fun loginUser(loginRequestModel: LoginRequestModel): APIResponse<LoginResponseDto, Exception> {
    return try {
        val response = httpClient.post("https://endpoint") {
            contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
            setBody(LoginRequestDto(/* body data */))
        }

        when (response.status.value) {
            200 -> APIResponse.Success(response.body())
            401 -> throw APIErrorException.InvalidCredentialsException("Invalid credentials provided")
            403 -> throw APIErrorException.AccessDeniedException("Access denied")
            404 -> throw APIErrorException.ResourceNotFoundException("Resource not found")
            else -> APIResponse.Failure(ErrorResponseDto(errors = listOf(ErrorDto("APIError", "Unknown error"))))
        }
    } catch (e: CancellationException) {
        Timber.e(e)
        //Maybe rethrow ?
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Timber.e(e)
        APIResponse.Error(e)
    }
}

